# How to check for empty array while spreading an array in function paramater

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am writing one method in my react application. In effect.js, i have written a function like below-

```
export async function getUserDetails(...request) {
  try {
    // TO DO
  } catch (e) {
    // To DO
  } finally {
    // TO DO
  }
}
```

My request will always be an array and hence i want to handle the scenario to check for empty array as well. I tried doing something like below but that gives me error. Can someone help me understand what i am doing wrong.

```
export async function getUserDetails([...requestPayload] = []) {
  try {
    // TO DO
  } catch (e) {
    // To DO
  } finally {
    // TO DO
  }
}
```

Comment: `request.length` would be zero, if the array is empty...

Comment: yes, but i want to add that check in parameter itself.

Comment: What DO you want to do if the array is empty, tough?

Comment: @VLAZ, i am doing one api call inside this method. Hence, to future-proof , i want to handle the situation where i do not have any request params, it should not go inside this method and break the flow.

Comment: @techiequestie how would "check in the parameter" help? You need logic that can *only* be part of the function to stop the execution early. You cannot abort function execution from within the parameter field. You can, at best, initialise some parameters if they weren't passed in or re-map some to different values via destructuring, rest, or whatever.

Comment: I am using rematch, so the request params directly come to this effects. I thought i can add an empty array check here.

Comment: First, no you cannot. Second, even if you *could*, you cannot stop the function from executing further. Parameter checks *only* change the parameters, they don't include execution logic.

Comment: ok, so it will not get aborted but in case where my request params are empty, it will not break right?

Comment: No. It cannot - there is nothing in the language that would allow for this. You need to do the check within the body of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate `request` variable like:

```
export async function getUserDetails(...request) {
  try {
    // TO DO
    request = !!request && request.length ? request : [];
  } catch (e) {
    // To DO
  } finally {
    // TO DO
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check on the length if you are sure that what you are receiving is an array.

Like this,

```
export async function getUserDetails(...request) {
  try {
      if(request.length){
          // TO DO
      }
  } catch (e) {
    // To DO
  } finally {
    // TO DO
  }
}
```